# Emoji has wrong size when using Text with bigger font size in Flutter

Tags: ios, flutter, dart, fonts

I'm using the `Text` widget in Flutter. When the `fontSize` gets bigger (about 83pts), emojis scale wrong. They seem to double their size but the non-emoji text scales right. I need to have really big texts in the app (supporting emojis) because they will almost fill up the screen.

I tried changing the font family but the same happens. Giving the text a smaller size and place it inside a `FittedBox` has the same result.

Here's what happens when changing the `fontSize`:
https://youtu.be/aKrc6VbIR80

[Screenshot with smaller font](https://i.stack.imgur.com/omK4A.png)

[Screenshot with bigger font](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zxQAn.png)

Here is the code I'm using to reproduce it:

```
    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
    import 'package:flutter/services.dart';

    class DebugScreen extends StatefulWidget {
      const DebugScreen({super.key});

      @override
      State<DebugScreen> createState() => _DebugScreenState();
    }

    class _DebugScreenState extends State<DebugScreen> {
      double fontSize = 12;

      @override
      void initState() {
        super.initState();

        SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations([
          DeviceOrientation.portraitUp,
          DeviceOrientation.landscapeLeft,
          DeviceOrientation.landscapeRight,
        ]);
      }

      Widget _debugBox(Widget child) {
        return Container(
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            border: Border.all(color: Colors.red, width: 1),
          ),
          child: child,
        );
      }

      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        final padding = MediaQuery.of(context).padding;
        return Scaffold(
          body: Stack(
            children: [
              Positioned(
                top: 50,
                left: 0,
                child: _debugBox(
                  Text(
                    "Hi ",
                    style: TextStyle(
                      fontSize: fontSize,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              Positioned(
                left: 50,
                right: 50,
                bottom: padding.bottom,
                child: Row(
                  children: [
                    Expanded(
                      child: Slider(
                        min: 2,
                        max: 500,
                        value: fontSize,
                        onChanged: (val) => setState(
                          () => fontSize = val,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    Text("Font size = ${fontSize.toInt()}"),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        );
      }
    }
```

Comment: Hey, can you change your branch to master and try it again? Looks like this issue: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/110726

Comment: Awesome! That is fixed in master. I tried the latest version but this fix is not present yet. I guess I'll need to wait for a release 

Comment: Unfortunately, yes, or you work with the master branch, which I would not recommend :D

Comment: I have the same problem. what is the solution?