# flutter emoji size jumps after 60ppx

Tags: flutter, font-size, emoji

What is the problem with the emoji font size over 60px?

[image]

I want to increase the emoji size but it does not work and jumps after the 60px

> this is my code:

```
class EmojiPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const EmojiPage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<EmojiPage> createState() => _EmojiPageState();
}

class _EmojiPageState extends State<EmojiPage> {
  int fontSize = 50;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
      children: [
        Text(
          'fontSize: ${fontSize}',
          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 21),
        ),
        Container(
          color: Colors.grey,
          child: Text('', style: TextStyle(fontSize: fontSize.toDouble())),
        ),
        const SizedBox(height: 50),
        Row(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            ElevatedButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  setState(() {
                    fontSize += 5;
                  });
                },
                child: Text(' + ')),
            const SizedBox(width: 10),
            ElevatedButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  setState(() {
                    fontSize -= 5;
                  });
                },
                child: Text(' - ')),
          ],
        )
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: your code does not have any probles. maybe its font issue

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73840255/emoji-has-wrong-size-when-using-text-with-bigger-font-size-in-flutter?noredirect=1#comment130399248_73840255  see this question and my answer

Comment: @targiasld 
thank you for your reply. I saw this question and answer but there is no solution.

Comment: Check if it's fixed in a stable version or try to use the master branch. But be careful since master is in development ^^

Comment: @targiasld ok let me try. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After weeks of effort and research, I found out that this problem is created in Flutter from version `>3.0.0` and up
I downgraded my Flutter version from `3.3.10` version to `3.0.0` and this problem is gone
Now.

[image]